# Will changing your SD card affect your New Leaf Game (Physical)?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Will it affect your *New Leaf* game if you have the physical copy but use a new SD card once the old one is full?

Answer (score 1):

All 3DS games save to the SD card. You can migrate your 3DS save files from one SD card to another by using a computer with an SD card reader to transfer the save and update files.

See the articles [here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/topics/detail/p/605/c/235) for 3DS file management.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a physical game cartridge of the game, the data should be saving to the cartridge, not the SD card. If you bought the game from the eShop or used a download code, it WILL save to the SD card.